# How can I change the Postgres data_directory folder location?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, database, postgresql, database-administration

I use Ubuntu 12.04, postgresql 9,1 postgis 1.5. I want to change database location. I use instruction http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2012/04/change-postgres-datadirectory-folder.html The only difference is that I do not use postgres account for changing file /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf

When I resatrt postgresql i have error:

```
Error: pid file is invalid
```

This error exists in the bug tracker https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-3618

How can I change the database location?

Comment: Have you tried "manually kill the stale server process" like suggested in the 2nd link you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appropriate tools - [`pg_createcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) in this case. Take a closer look at its `--datadir=` option.